# Do we need custom client side validation if we use Angular 6?

Tags: angular, forms, validation

I am new to Angular 6 (total Angular Platform for sure..), and have following problem. I know that Angular 6 uses very strong client side user input validation method(s). Therefor, do we need to use any other client side validation methods (for standard issues such as number, email address, special characters, essential form fields etc...) than these standard methods? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular

> provides a set of built-in validators that can be used by form
>   controls

https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators

For a lot of applications, these validators might be enough, but Angular also let's you define your own. I needed a validator that determined if the input was a valid number:

```
    static numValidator(): ValidatorFn {
        return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } => {
            if (!control) {
                return {};
            }
            const value = control.value;

            if (!value) {
                return {};
            }
            else if (isNaN(parseFloat(value)) || !isFinite(value)) {
                return { 'number': true }
            }

            return {};
        };
    }
```

Use like this:

```
inputYear: [, [FormUtils.numValidator(), FormUtils.numLengthValidator(4)]],
```

Validation Messages:

```
validationMessages = {
    inputYear: { number: 'Must be a number', length: 'Must be 4 digits' }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on your requirements. E.g if you have different scenarios for email validation but Angular provides something else which is not fitting into your requirement then you have to write custom validation for it. That's why Angular also provides the way to write custom validations you will find [here](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#cross-field-validation).